# Functional Index LOWER PostgreSQL not working

Tags: postgresql, index, case-sensitive

The below SQL query runs in 2s:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    fb_name
    INNER JOIN fb_kg ON mid = subject_mid
    WHERE
        LOWER(alias) = LOWER('Polaski')
        AND fb_kg.relation = 'location/location/containedby'
```

The below SQL query runs in 2ms:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    fb_name
    INNER JOIN fb_kg ON mid = subject_mid
    WHERE
        alias = 'Polaski'
        AND fb_kg.relation = 'location/location/containedby'
```

The difference between the two queries is the inclusion of the LOWER function.

There has been an index created for both queries:

```
CREATE INDEX fb_name_lower_alias ON fb_name (lower(alias));
CREATE INDEX fb_name_mid_lower_alias_index ON fb_name (mid, lower(alias));
CREATE INDEX fb_name_alias ON fb_name (alias);
CREATE INDEX fb_name_mid_alias_index ON fb_name (mid, alias);
```

EXPLAIN for LOWER:

```
"Gather  (cost=247515.73..249133.22 rows=5708 width=70)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=246515.73..247562.42 rows=2378 width=70)"
"        Merge Cond: ((fb_kg.subject_mid)::text = (fb_name.mid)::text)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=205352.30..205794.73 rows=176972 width=44)"
"              Sort Key: fb_kg.subject_mid"
"              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on fb_kg  (cost=14116.24..184480.39 rows=176972 width=44)"
"                    Recheck Cond: ((relation)::text = 'location/location/containedby'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on relation_index  (cost=0.00..14010.06 rows=424733 width=0)"
"                          Index Cond: ((relation)::text = 'location/location/containedby'::text)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=41163.43..41232.45 rows=27611 width=26)"
"              Sort Key: fb_name.mid"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on fb_name  (cost=750.54..39126.71 rows=27611 width=26)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (lower((alias)::text) = 'polaski'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fb_name_lower_alias_varchar_pattern_ops  (cost=0.00..743.64 rows=27611 width=0)"
"                          Index Cond: (lower((alias)::text) = 'polaski'::text)"
```

Other EXPLAIN:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=11.45..13502.52 rows=2 width=70)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on fb_name  (cost=4.64..48.23 rows=11 width=26)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((alias)::text = 'Polaski'::text)"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fb_name_alias_index  (cost=0.00..4.64 rows=11 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: ((alias)::text = 'Polaski'::text)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on fb_kg  (cost=6.81..1223.04 rows=8 width=44)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((subject_mid)::text = (fb_name.mid)::text)"
"        Filter: ((relation)::text = 'location/location/containedby'::text)"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on subject_mid_index  (cost=0.00..6.81 rows=316 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: ((subject_mid)::text = (fb_name.mid)::text)"
```

CREATE TABLE definitions

```
CREATE TABLE fb_kg
        (object_mid varchar NOT NULL,
        relation varchar NOT NULL,
        subject_mid varchar NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(object_mid, relation, subject_mid));

CREATE TABLE fb_name
    (mid varchar NOT NULL,
    alias varchar NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(mid, alias));
```

How come with the same indexes the LOWER function is about 60x slower?

Comment: these query plans are totally useless, they're `ANALYZE`, we need `ANALYZE EXPLAIN` You need to reperform both of tohse with `ANALYZE EXPLAIN` if you want a direct answer, but either way you should take my advice on the citext module.

Comment: Did you ANALYZE the table after building the functional index?

Answer (score 1):

## Using [`citext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html)

My suggestion is to move to the citext module.

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
BEGIN;
  --out with the old
  DROP INDEX fb_name_lower_alias;
  DROP INDEX fb_name_mid_lower_alias_index;
  DROP INDEX fb_name_alias;
  DROP INDEX fb_name_mid_alias_index;

  --in with the new
  ALTER TABLE fb_name
    ALTER COLUMN alias
    SET DATA TYPE citext;

  CREATE INDEX ON fb_name(mid,alias);
  CREATE INDEX ON fb_name(alias);
  ANALYZE fb_name;
COMMIT;
```

Then simply stop using `lower()` everywhere. Your query should like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM fb_name
INNER JOIN fb_kg ON mid = subject_mid
WHERE alias = 'Polaski'
  AND fb_kg.relation = 'location/location/containedby';
```

Everything else should work the same. Paste the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the new query.

## Update on indexes, and case-sensitive searching on `citext`

If  you need a case-sensitive query on a `citext` column, you just have to cast the other side to `::text`, and in fact using the `citext` index is usually good enough. For example you can do a case-sensitive index only scan with `WHERE col::citext = 'fOo'::citext AND col::text = 'fOo'`; or, you could create two indexes on the `citext` column:

- one that's case sensitive `ON table(myCITEXT)`
- one that's case insensitive (I find that wasteful though) `ON table(myCITEXT::text)`

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY fb_name_lower_alias, this worked for me